# Approximation String Match in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am writing a small utility where I want to filter the most relevant results based on the searched values:

For example : If the user has searched for "just for fun linus" , and my search result is following:

1. "Just for Girls"
2. "Just for Fun: Easy Rock Banjo"
3. "Just For Fun: The Story Of An Accidental Revolutionary Linus Torvalds"

my algorithm should give highest weight to the last one. Currently I have a homegrown algorithm which uses soundex match to give weight but fails sometimes.

Is there a ruby gem that can give me best possible way to find the nearest matching string ? I tried using 'amatch' - but its not giving correct match weights.

Comment: What is your database? If you use mysql there are some built in functions there that solve this problem. I'm sure other databases have something similar.

Comment: what about just counting identical downcased words?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a gem - amatch - which does this task really well

Comment: I tried all of the algorithms included with Amatch with your examples. `LongestSubsequence` was the only one that gave the highest weight to `Just For Fun: The Story Of An Accidental Revolutionary Linus Torvalds`. None of the edit distance ones (`Hamming`, `Jaro`, `JaroWinkler`, `Levenshtein`, or `Sellers`) did. Or `PairDistance` (common bigrams divided by all bigrams) or `LongestSubstring`.